# member.roles.add is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I don't know why but I get this error in the console when someone joins the server and doesn't want to give it a role

Error:
`TypeError: member.roles.add is not a function`

```
let roleID = "1005089670629175439";
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member, roleID) => {
    member.roles.add(roleID);
    console.log("Mistic BOT | Added role for new user");
});
```

Comment: This won't fix your issue, but the listener for `guildMemberAdd` takes one parameter, `member`, not two.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: You should also use `.add()` with a `Role` object, not a string.

Comment: `member.roles.add(1005089670629175439);`
Work't, same error

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, I'm just starting with js and I don't know what you mean @ZsoltMeszaros

Comment: Somewhere you've instantiated your `client` and you should have an `intents` array added there.

Comment: It's index.js
`const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Discord.Client(); 

// Other scripts
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
 member.roles.add("1005089670629175439");
 console.log("Mistic BOT | Added role for new user");
});`

Comment: @KarolLewandowski Your code shows that you aren't even having the bot log in with `client.login()`.

Comment: Before you start using discord.js, you need to have a good grip on JavaScript. Then, you should go through the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin) to get started with discord.js.

Comment: I has client.login

Comment: Its index.js:
https://pastebin.com/RYLc2ur3

Answer (score 0):

First check if you enabled privileged intents on discord developer portal.
This is how you do it

1. Make sure you're logged on to the Discord website.
2. Navigate to the application page.
3. Click on the bot you want to enable privileged intents for.
4. Navigate to the bot tab on the left side of the screen.
5. Scroll down to the “Privileged Gateway Intents” section and enable server members intent.

On your code you don't need to pass the roleID if its in the same file just simply use something like this

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    let roleID = "1005089670629175439";
    member.roles.add(roleID); 
    console.log("Mistic BOT | Added role 
    for new user"); 
});
```

Comment: `/home/container/index.js:28
    member.roles.add(roleID); 
                 ^
TypeError: member.roles.add is not a function`

Comment: Same error, this is code:
`client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    let roleID = "1005089670629175439";
    member.roles.add(roleID); 
    console.log("Mistic BOT | Added role for new user"); 
});`

Comment: Its index.js:
https://pastebin.com/RYLc2ur3

Comment: Privileged Gateway Intents is enabled